# The container alignment is out of proportion

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

[image]

I wanted the lower container with blue background to align with the top container but I noticed that the ticket_screen isn't getting the size that's assigned in the app_layout when I called it using the `final size = AppLayout.getSize(context)`. I'm not getting any error is the terminal and I can't locate the bug.

````
`
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AppLayout {
  static getSize(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  }

  static getScreenHeight() {
    return Get.height;
  }

  static getScreenWidth() {
    return Get.width;
  }

  static getHeight(double pixels) {
    double x = getScreenHeight() / pixels;
    return getScreenHeight() / x;
  }

  static getWidth(double pixels) {
    double x = getScreenWidth() / pixels;
    return getScreenWidth() / x;
  }
}

```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/screens/ticket_view.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_info_list.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_layout.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/widgets/ticket_tabs.dart';

import '../utils/app_styles.dart';

class TicketScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TicketScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = AppLayout.getSize(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: AppLayout.getHeight(20),
              vertical: AppLayout.getHeight(20)),
          children: [
            Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(40)),
            Text(
              'Tickets',
              style: Styles.headLineStyle,
            ),
            Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(20)),
            const AppTicketsTab(firstTab: 'Upcoming', secondTab: 'Previous'),
            Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(20)),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: AppLayout.getHeight(15)),
              child: TicketView(
                ticket: ticketList[0],
                isColor: true,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Flutter DB',
                            style: Styles.headLineStyle3,
                          ),
                          Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(5)),
                          Text(
                            'Passenger',
                            style: Styles.headLineStyle3,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_layout.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_styles.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/widgets/thick_container.dart';

class TicketView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> ticket;
  final bool? isColor;
  const TicketView({
    Key? key,
    required this.ticket,
    this.isColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = AppLayout.getSize(context);
    return SizedBox(
      width: size.width * 0.85,
      height: AppLayout.getHeight(GetPlatform.isAndroid == true ? 169 : 169),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: AppLayout.getHeight(16)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            /*
              SHOWING THE PURPLE PART OF THE CARD TICKET
              */
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isColor == null ? Color(0xFF8E24AA) : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(21)),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(16)),
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppLayout.getHeight(16)),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        ticket['from']['code'],
                        style: isColor == null
                            ? Styles.headLineStyle3
                                .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                            : Styles.headLineStyle3,
                      ),
                      Expanded(child: Container()),
                      ThickContainer(
                        isColor: true,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: AppLayout.getHeight(24),
                            child: LayoutBuilder(
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  BoxConstraints constraints) {
                                print(
                                    'The width is ${constraints.constrainWidth()}');
                                return Flex(
                                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: List.generate(
                                      (constraints.constrainWidth() / 6)
                                          .floor(),
                                      ((index) => SizedBox(
                                            width: 3,
                                            height: 1,
                                            child: DecoratedBox(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: isColor == null
                                                    ? Colors.white
                                                    : Colors.grey.shade300,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ))),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: Transform.rotate(
                              angle: 1.5,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.local_airport_rounded,
                                color: isColor == null
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Color(0xFFBACCF7),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                      ThickContainer(
                        isColor: true,
                      ),
                      Expanded(child: Container()),
                      Text(
                        ticket['to']['code'],
                        style: isColor == null
                            ? Styles.headLineStyle3.copyWith(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            : Styles.headLineStyle3,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Gap(3),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: AppLayout.getWidth(100),
                        child: Text(ticket['from']['name'],
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle4
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle4),
                      ),
                      Text(ticket['flying_time'],
                          style: isColor == null
                              ? Styles.headLineStyle3
                                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                              : Styles.headLineStyle4),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: AppLayout.getWidth(100),
                        child: Text(ticket['to']['name'],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle4
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle4),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            /* 
              SHOWING THE Pink PART OF CART TICKET
              */
            Container(
              color: isColor == null ? Styles.pinkColor : Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: AppLayout.getHeight(20),
                    width: AppLayout.getWidth(10),
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: isColor == null ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(10)),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(10)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder:
                            (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                          return Flex(
                            direction: Axis.horizontal,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: List.generate(
                              (constraints.constrainWidth() / 15).floor(),
                              (index) => SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                                height: 1,
                                child: DecoratedBox(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: isColor == null
                                          ? Colors.white
                                          : Colors.grey.shade300),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: AppLayout.getHeight(20),
                    width: AppLayout.getWidth(10),
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: isColor == null ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(10)),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(10)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            /*
            Bottom part of the card ticket
             */
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: isColor == null ? Styles.pinkColor : Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular((isColor == null ? 21 : 0)),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular((isColor == null ? 21 : 0)),
                  )),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            ticket['date'],
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle3
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle3,
                          ),
                          const Gap(5),
                          Text(
                            'Date',
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle4
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle4,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            ticket['departure_time'],
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle3
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle3,
                          ),
                          const Gap(5),
                          Text(
                            'Departure time',
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle4
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle4,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            ticket['number'].toString(),
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle3
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle3,
                          ),
                          const Gap(5),
                          Text(
                            'Number',
                            style: isColor == null
                                ? Styles.headLineStyle4
                                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white)
                                : Styles.headLineStyle4,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
````

The blue background color is just to show the size of the container, it's supposed to be white and also have the same size of the upper container.

Comment: If possible add an mvp, it can be in a github gist, but something functional so that we can debug. There are data and widgets that we don't have access to.

Comment: The blue container must have the same margin as the ticker_view. `margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: AppLayout.getHeight(16), left: AppLayout.getHeight(16)),` With this it will be in the same proportion as the white containers.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it worked. From my code, it was supposed to work immediately i called the AppLayout size.

Comment: And the then the blue container was supposed to be right under the ticket container without any gap between them so that it'll look like one container.

Comment: I realised that the size variable isn't used even though i called it. So i want the two containers to be together without a space in between them.